# A compact subset of a manifold can be expressed as a finite union of compact subsets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

Given a $n - $ manifold $M$ with orientation $\mu$  and a compact subset $K$ . I want to prove that there exist a homology class $\mu_{K} \in H_{n}(M,M - K)$ such that :

$$\rho_{x}(\mu_{K})=\mu_{x}$$

for each $x \in K$

About orientation and notations , I always assume $M$ is $n$ - dimensional manifold

Notation : $\rho_{B}$ is induced by inclusion which assigns a homology class of $H_{n}(M,M-A)$ to a homology class of $H_{n}(M,M-B)$ ( for any subset $B \subset A $ )

Orientation : A manifold $M$ always satisfy the following :

$$H_{n}(M, M - x) \cong H_{n}(\mathbb{R^{n}},\mathbb{R^{n}}-x)\cong \mathbb{Z}$$

Each of choice the generator of $H_{n}(M , M - x)$ is called a local orientaion . $M$ has an orientation if every point $x \in X$ has a neighborhood $N$ and a function assigns $x$ to $\mu_{x} \in H_{n}(M,M-x)$  and an element $\mu_{N} \in H_{n}(M , M - N) : i_{*}(\mu_{N})=\mu_{x=y}$ with homomorphism induced by inclusion :

$$i_{*} : H_{n}(M , M - N) \to H_{n}(M , M - y)$$

For each $y \in N$

The proof based on the fact that $K$ can be expressed as a finite union of compact subsets , each of which sufficiently small for existence of $\mu_{K_{i}}$ ( if it is small enough then it is contained in a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ , so the existence is obvious from orientaion )

But maybe I'm confusing , I don't know how to seperate $K$ to union of compacts subsets satisfy above conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest idea IMHO: let $K \subseteq M$ compact. Say we need sets of diameter $<d$. Then cover $K$ by the sets $B(x, \frac{d}{3}) ,x \in K$. Finitely many cover $K$ by compactness, and then take the closures of those finitely many $\overline{B(x,\frac{d}{3})} \cap K$, which are compact and of diameter $\le \frac{2d}{3}< d$.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question about this topic ?

Comment: @BangPhamKhoa what?

Comment: The balls are taken withe respect to which metric? Are you taking these balls in a local coordinate of $x$, and then bringing them back to $M$? Or are you thinking of $M$ as a subset of some $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, for some $m$ and then taking the balls in that metric?

Comment: @feynhat I suppose the question pertains to metrisable manifolds.  Take any compatible metric.